# Does Stack Exchange merge edit branches?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, implementation

## Update:

The [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) is not a duplicate to this question for a simple reason: ***the suggested duplicate does not explain how StackExchange deals with conflicting edits in the queue***. And the fact that the suggested duplicate references a *queue* that can be *filled up* makes me begin to doubt the accepted answer to my question.

***To clarify the answer to my question in light of the linked suggested duplicate: is the review queue in question filled up by total edits to all questions, or number of edits to a given question. If the latter, how many edits fills up this queue to a single question, and how are conflicting suggested edits to a given question handled?***

Note: this question is very much about implementation: I want to know how StackExchange internally handles suggested edits. For some reason someone edited my question to remove the implementation tag. I am re-adding it in light of the suggested duplicatee.

---

Perhaps this is a duplicate, but I can't find the answer.

SE uses review queues to approve suggested edits. What happens when more than one edits are suggested before any are approved? Is the result a branch or does the new edit edit the previously suggested edit? And if it is a branch, does SE merge the edits when they are both approved?

Comment: You can't suggest another edit until the pending one is approved or rejected.

Comment: @greg-449 Ah, well, that would be a quite feasible solution. Post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I was actually expecting git-like diff and merge.

Comment: Now that I think of it though, you'd end up with edit collision over minor grammatical mistakes: too many useless changes where one would suit.

Comment: The review queue contains all suggested edits to all questions, since reviewers are expected to visit the queue as the central place to handle reviews as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't suggest another edit until the pending one is approved or rejected. So the problem doesn't arise.

Reviewers can choose to improve the edit or reject and do a new edit.

Comment: Also worth to mention that the user who suggested the edit can override it by suggesting a new edit.

Comment: @greg-449: Please see update.

Comment: @malan You can suggest edits to different questions up to the limit - you can't suggest multiple edits to a single question.